# Elasticsearch analyze/ignore whitespaces in keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version : 6.8.5

I wonder if this is actually available.
I have some entries like this
- 100 x 2c ABSD
- 100 x 3a DDDDD

And I want to get both result when using "100 x" or "100x" as keywords

so far only this keyword works `100 x`